# I cannot get closed captions to appear in HTML5 videos

Tags: html, video, captions, closed-captions

I'm trying to get closed captions for an HTML video.

Right now I have:

```
<video  width="320" height="240" id="video" controls>
<source type="video/mp4" src="file.mp4" >
<track id="video1" src="file1.srt" label="English Captions" kind="captions" srclang="en-us" default> 
</video>
```

I've tried a lot of variations on this, including using different caption formats like .VTT but I cannot get anything to work.I've tried multiple different browsers, but I can't even get the CC button to appear. Any idea what I'm doing work, or are there any comprehensive tutorials on it? I've found a number of tutorials online, but none of them seem to resolve the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Show the contents of the `.vtt` file.

Comment: My .vtt file reads:

WEBVTT

00:04.333 --> 00:08.333
Making a successful flying machine
requires doing a lot of things right.

00:08.333 --> 00:12.333
Many people have tried to duplicate birds

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome v.35. What browser do you use ? Do you recieve any error messages ?

Comment: I've tried it with Google Chrome v.35, Firefox v.29 and IE v.9

Comment: I've found that when using Opera I get this error: Text track from origin 'file://' has been blocked from loading: Not at same origin as the document, and parent of track element does not have a 'crossorigin' attribute. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: That had no effect. I got the same error message.

Comment: Error message is pretty much self-explanatory. If you are testing this example locally, start Chrome with `--disable-web-security` flag to avoid 'file://' origin violation. For more information about CORS, visit this [page](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/).

Comment: I have disabled web security, but I get the same error. Any ideas there?

Comment: See https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=103110#c1 - CORS on the video element influences the track element

Comment: `chrome.exe --disable-web-security` in cmd solved this for me. [see answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome]

Answer (score -1):

Is your timed text file (.vtt file) in the same directory as the mp4 video? If yes, try using the same file name for the video and vtt files but using their respective file extensions.

Comment: An .srt file will not work with HTML5 videos in the browser. i.e. You must use a .vtt file.